# Dynamics 365 - Field Service : The scope 'Odata.FullAccess' does not exist

Tags: python-3.x, azure, flask, azure-active-directory, microsoft-dynamics

## The case : CRUD Work Orders in Dynamics 365-Field Service through the Common Data Services OData

1. I am trying to access to Dynamics 365 Field Service' fields.

I use **Python**, **Flask** to build the webapp

2. I need to CRUD Work orders : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/web-api/msdyn_workorder?view=dynamics-ce-odata-9
3. I am using the multi-tenant server-to-server authentication mechanism:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/common-data-service/use-multi-tenant-server-server-authentication
4. I have setup the App Registration on Azure: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-register-app
5. I have configured several permissions:

- Odata.FullAccess
- AX.FullAccess
- CustomService.FullAccess
- User.Read
- User.ReadBasic.All

[image: Azure App Registration : Configured permissions]

6. I use the code-template provided by Microsoft to build my web app interacting with Active Directory and Dynamics 365

   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-web-app-call-api-overview

## Error message

```
Login Failure

invalid_scope
    The provided value for the input parameter 'scope' is not valid. 
    The scope 'Odata.FullAccess User.ReadBasic.All offline_access openid profile' 
    does not exist.
```

### Do you have any idea?

Many thanks for the time you will invest in this issue

Comment: How  are you sending the scope?  Is it URL encoded?  e.g. `scope=user.read%20mail.read`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [Grant your application rights to access Common Data Service data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/common-data-service/use-multi-tenant-server-server-authentication#grant-your-application-rights-to-access-common-data-service-data), you need to select **Access Dynamics 365 as organization users**.

[image]

It is under Dynamics CRM rather than Dynamics ERP.

[image]

`Odata.FullAccess` is a permission under Dynamics ERP, which is not valid for your scene.

Comment: @allan-wu, I addressed the issue differently. 

I removed ALL scopes and the authentication mechanisms worked. 
I'll try your solution though.

Many thanks